# OpenID Connect not working with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, openid-connect

I'm operating an ASP.NET MVC application that leverages Microsoft OpenID Connect.

(manual : https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp)

We began our service in October 2019, and had no problems with it until now. After the last successful log in, we are facing authorization failure in the redirected part and cannot verify the Claim (`User.Identity`) information, hence resulting in an infinite loop issue.

I hope I can get assistance with this problem.

After logging in successfully, I store the authentication information so that I can share the token value in the RESTful API which is configured separately.

In the earlier version, the token value was stored in the `Token` table and was stored in the session.

But when I started to used the session from the second attempt, the problem started to occur so I started not to use the session.

At this point, I tried several login attempts and saw that it worked well without a problem.

Initially, the application was properly working, but as time passed by, I can no longer retrieve the authentication information and an infinite loop occurs once again.

Code:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties{ RedirectUri = "/Auth/SignedIn" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}

public void SignOut()
{
    this.RemoveSessionToken();

    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> SignedIn()
{
    var IsLoggedIn = Request.IsAuthenticated;
    var claims = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;

    if (IsLoggedIn)
    {
        var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
        //string sessionToken = Session.SessionID;
        string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 


        var dbContext = new GetOfficeEduUsersEntities();
        var token = new T_APIToken();
        string office365Id = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;

        token.TokenID = office365Id;
        token.IssuerID = office365Id; 
        token.IssueDT = DateTime.Now;
        token.ExpireDT = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(180);

        dbContext.T_APIToken.Add(token);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        //Error
        return RedirectToAction("SignedIn"); 
    }
}
```